# Align image to baseline with css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am attempting to align an image to the baseline of an `h1` What's the best way for doing this?

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

html,body, .header{
  height: 100%;
background-color: peachpuff;
  }
.header{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [left-gutter] 1fr [title] 4fr [image] 8fr [right-gutter] 1fr;}
.header__title{
      grid-column: title;
      align-self: center;
      }
.header__image-wrapper{
      grid-column: image;
      align-self: baseline;
      }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="header__title">Title</h1>
  <div class="header__image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?water" alt="random" />
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't align grid items with `baseline` because `baseline` is not a valid value for `align-self` property or `align-items` property in-case of CSS grid. Valid values for both these properties, in case of grid, are `start | end | center | stretch`. You can align flex items with `align-self: baseline` or `align-items: baseline`.

Add `align-self: end` to `.header__title` element to align the text at the end of the row and remove `100%` width from `html`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
.header {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [left-gutter] 1fr [title] 4fr [image] 8fr [right-gutter] 1fr;
}

.header__title {
  grid-column: title;
  align-self: end;
  margin: 0;
}

.header__image-wrapper {
  grid-column: image;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="header__title">Title</h1>
  <div class="header__image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200/?water" alt="random" />
  </div>
</header>
```